# Could Not Show Date in X-Axis More than Once in MPAndroidChart (LineChart)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, mpandroidchart

I have a GraphActivity class which includes all graph activities. Also Realtime Database are running in this class. The GraphActivity class is as below:

```
package com.example.basardesktop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.basardesktop.MainActivity.dbDate;

import static com.example.basardesktop.MainActivity.newDate;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import static com.example.basardesktop.MainActivity.price;
import static com.example.basardesktop.MainActivity.productName;


import com.example.basardesktop.R;
import com.example.basardesktop.databinding.ActivityGraphBinding;
import com.example.basardesktop.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class GraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static int dbPrice;
    MainActivity mn = new MainActivity();

    private ActivityGraphBinding binding;
    private LineChart chart;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityGraphBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        Button buttonCopy = binding.buttonCopy;
        chart = findViewById(R.id.lineChart);


        // Configure chart appearance and settings
        chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        chart.setDragEnabled(true);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        chart.setPinchZoom(true);
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

        // Customize the X-axis
        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        // X-axis value formatter

        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            private final long startDate = getMillisFromString(newDate);

            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                if (value == 0) {
                    return dateFormat.format(new Date(startDate));
                } else if (value == 1) {
                    long millis = (long) value + startDate;
                    Date date = new Date(millis);
                    return dateFormat.format(date);
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        });


        // Y-axis setup and configuration
        YAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxis.setDrawZeroLine(true);
        yAxis.setDrawTopYLabelEntry(true);
        yAxis.setGranularity(1); // Minimum interval on the Y-axis
        yAxis.setTextSize(12f);

        YAxis rightYAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
        rightYAxis.setEnabled(false);

        // Y-axis value formatter
        yAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                return value + " ₺";
            }
        });

        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        mn.db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mn.reference = mn.db.getReference("Detected Text");
        mn.reference = mn.db.getReference("Date");
        mn.reference.push().setValue(newDate);


        mn.reference = mn.db.getReference("Price");
        mn.reference.push().setValue(price);


        mn.reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //newDate = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    dbPrice = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    System.out.println("berat1 " + dbPrice);
                    price = dbPrice;
                    System.out.println("berat2 " + dbPrice);

                    Long longVal = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                    newDate = longVal.toString();

                    entries.add(new Entry(getMillisFromString(newDate), price));


                }

                LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, productName);

                dataSet.setCircleRadius(6f);
                dataSet.setValueTextSize(10f);

                // Value formatter for data labels
                dataSet.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                        return value + " ₺";
                    }
                });

                ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
                dataSets.add(dataSet);

                LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);

                chart.setData(lineData);
                dataSet.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lineData.notifyDataChanged();
                chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                chart.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e("Firebase", "Veri çekme hatası: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });


        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, productName);


        dataSet.setCircleRadius(6f);
        dataSet.setValueTextSize(10f);

        // Value formatter for data labels
        dataSet.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                return value + " ₺";
            }
        });


        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(dataSet);

        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);

        chart.setData(lineData);
        dataSet.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lineData.notifyDataChanged();
        chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chart.invalidate();


    }


    private long getMillisFromString(String dateString) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(dateString);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

In this class, I can send the data to the Realtime Database successfully with push() method. After pushing them to the Realtime Database I retrieve data with DataSnapshot. I send the Date values as an x-axis and price as a y-axis. Although I can observe different price values in the Graph, I can not see all the Date values that I sent. I can only observe the last Date data that I sent in the entries list. What is the problem in the code? How can I observe all Date values on the x-axis ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiwEM.png)

As you can see, the last date data is shown in the graph without showing previous date datas.

Comment: If this is a question about how to make the chart, it would be easier to answer if you had a minimum complete example that doesn't depend on your database (that someone else could run). The static "newDate" variable looks suspicious (generally a bad idea) - your value formatter is going to be using the updated value there which is possibly the issue. Try using a local (non-static) variable instead of "newDate" inside the "onDataChange" method. If that doesn't work, post a minimum example someone else could run (and confirm that the x values you add to "entries" are what you expect)

Comment: Also, just noticed `MainActivity mn = new MainActivity();` - if that is an actual activity, you should definitely not be doing that. You should *never* create an activity directly like that.

Comment: Finally, in your axis value formatter, you are using `long startDate = getMillisFromString(newDate);` as though `newDate` is a dd.MM.yyyy date string, but in your snapshow listener you are treating it as a string representation of a long value (`newDate = longVal.toString();`) - which is it?